# Python: fillna() function is outputting the word "None"

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to perform an exercise for a class, wherein I have to use the fillna() function to replace the missing values of a column with the median of the data.  In the DataFrame referred to as "housing", there is a column entitled "Mas Vnr Area" which has a few rows which have "NA" values.  In order to fill and verify these changes, I have been using the following lines of code (using the PyCharm IDE) after reading the necessary .csv file:

```
median_val = housing["Mas Vnr Area"].median()

print(housing["Mas Vnr Area"].fillna(median_val,inplace = True))
```

However, every time I run this program, this portion of the code just outputs the word "None."  I have verified multiple times that "housing" has the requisite information inside of it, but I get this output every single time.  Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this?

Comment: The `inplace` parameter is working exactly as it should; do you know what it means? Please read the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html). If it's changing it in-place, then that would surely mean that `housing["Mas Vnr Area"]` now has the changed data, and that `fillna(median,inplace = True)` is going to return nothing (which implicitly is `None` in Python).

Comment: This is the same as how `[3,2,1].sort()` also returns `None`, as does _every other_ in-place function that follows standard conventions.

Answer (score 0):

As you get in comment: `inplace` means `in-place` and it changes value in original `DataFrame` without returning new `DataFrame`. So it only returns (default) `None`.

So you have to first use function with `inplace` and later display it.

```
median_val = housing["Mas Vnr Area"].median()

housing["Mas Vnr Area"].fillna(median_val, inplace=True)

print(housing["Mas Vnr Area"])
```

Or you should run without `inplace`

```
median_val = housing["Mas Vnr Area"].median()

print(housing["Mas Vnr Area"].fillna(median_val))
```

but this will loose changes - and it may need to assign new value to old place (or to other place)

```
median_val = housing["Mas Vnr Area"].median()

housing["Mas Vnr Area"] = housing["Mas Vnr Area"].fillna(median_val)  # assign to old palce
#housing["new column"] = housing["Mas Vnr Area"].fillna(median_val)   # assign to new place

print(housing["Mas Vnr Area"])
```

---

So these two lines do the same

```
housing["Mas Vnr Area"].fillna(median_val, inplace=True)  # with `inplace`

housing["Mas Vnr Area"] = housing["Mas Vnr Area"].fillna(median_val)   # without `inplace`
```